# Android Studio - how to enable Kotlin documentation in Flutter project?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, kotlin

I need to add some platform specific code and I would like to have a possibility to show quick kotlin documentation when press ctr+q. How can I achieve that, other than opening a kotlin file through file -> open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer by accident - in settings -> languages & frameworks there's an experimental feature, which helps to show quick documentation.

[image: Highlighted option]